# Single table/model with secondary models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have a model called `Keyboard`. Is there a way to create two sub models called `MechanicalKeyboard` and `ChicletKeyboard`?

The sub models have slightly different controller and view logic, so I want to break those out of the main model -- but there will still be only one table/main model.

The sub models will use the same attributes. I tried to use an `enum` for this, but separate controller and views make more sense.

Is that possible in Rails?

Comment: Are those 2 models will be using the same attributes?

Comment: so they will have just some different behaviours. you can do inheritance then, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It's called [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html). You just need to add a new attribute to your `Keyboard` model called `type`:

```
class AddTypeToKeyboards < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :keyboards, :type, :string
  end
end
```

Then, you define your tables inheriting them from your main model:

```
# app/models/mechanical_keyboard.rb
class MechanicalKeyboard < Keyboard
  # Custom validations and methods go here.
end

# app/models/chiclet_keyboard.rb
class ChicletKeyboard < Keyboard
  # Custom validations and methods go here.
end
```

They'll use the very same table `keyboards`, and share the same attributes (columns). To create, update, query or manage keyboards, you can use whatever class you want. Rails will handle the `type` value automatically. For example, to retrieve all the mechanical keyboards, you can use `MechanicalKeyboard.all`, which is equivalent to `Keyboard.where(type: 'MechanicalKeyboard')`.

Comment: Thanks @Wikiti -- is it a good practice to create `resources` for these sub models in routes file?

Comment: Yes. Just threath them as different models.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!